# RoR and AngularJS Integeration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am building an app with following technologies
 1. RoR - BackEnd
 2. Angular JS - FrontEnd

In this case RoR should handle all the backend stuff (Model and Controller) and Angular JS should handle the stuff which should with handled by RoR View. So my question is that how we can communicate between these two different technologies. If possible, also suggest some tutorials for the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS is the client side JavaScript Framework and it works on the MVC design pattern. while Ruby on Rails is a server-side application framework based on MVC design pattern. The points below is a quick representation of how Angular JS works seamlessly with RAILS MVC.
The power of Angular JS is the client side data manipulations which we use for various User Interface Use Cases like Lists, Refine Search, and Graphical Data Representation etc and present the Web Application to the user as a Single Page Application.
Building the single-page applications using Angular JS and Ruby on Rail is a two-step process: first, you create a JSON API in Rails and then you use that API in the JavaScript application.
The Angular JS Controllers interact with RAILS Controllers. The object data from the RAILS Model (M) is passed to the Angular JS Controllers via Rails Controller(C) using Restful API services. The view part of the application is the Angular JS framework in MVC design pattern, dropping the View in Rails.
This way the true potential of Angular JS is utilized for building the Single Page Application and Rails is capitalized for its server-side implementation using its Models and Controllers. The layers interact using Restful JSON API services. Hire a ruby on rails developer for more detailed information.